# Anaconda R environment can't access libraries/packages when in R project of github repository

Tags: r, anaconda, renv

I have an R environment in Anaconda with all the packages I need and use. I added a private repository from github onto my pc using the conda CLI. The project files includes an renv folder as well a .Rproj file. When I try to open any of the R scripts in the project without opening the Rproj file to open the project, they all show up as blank, and when I try to open a csv file it says it doesn't exist. When I open the Rproject, I cannot access any of my libraries or packages that I usually have access to in R. When I tried to install a package in this environment, I got the error:

```
warning in system(paste(cmd, "shlib-clean")) : 'make' not found warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found error: compilation failed for package 'pkgload' * removing 'c:/users/poona/<repo name>/renv/staging/1/pkgload'
```

What's going wrong? I just want to access the scripts of the repository and load the packages of my usual environment. Any help is appreciated!